# C# how to add data into excel with no headers

Tags: c#, oledb

I tried searching for examples and never i found an example for inserting data into an empty excel.

```
Insert into [Sheet1$] (columnname1, columnName2) values ("somevalue","somevalue");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a simple way to create a file that can be read in excel. The simple solution I use many times, when I don't need any advanced features of excel sheets, is a CSV (comma seperated value).
You format your data like this :

```
COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3
ROW1_VALUE1,ROW1_VALUE2,ROW1_VALUE3
ROW2_VALUE1,ROW2_VALUE2,ROW2_VALUE3
```

Between the lines there are linebreaks. On Windows use `\r\n`.
You can construct the file any way that you wish, for example :

```
File.WriteAllText("test.csv","product,price\r\nbook,100\r\ncoffee,500");
```

This will produce a CSV that can be read in excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
Excel.Worksheet oSheet;

//------
oSheet.Cells[Row,Column] = "Some Info";

// --- Row & Column starts with 1
```

Comment: I want to use oledb only and not the interop